# How can you choose the network interface via which UDP broadcast packet is sent

Tags: ruby, sockets, networking, udp

If I send a UDP packet containing 'foo' like this:

```
socket = UDPSocket.new
socket.setsockopt(Socket::SOL_SOCKET, Socket::SO_BROADCAST, true)
socket.send('foo', 0, '<broadcast>', 40001)
```

then wireshark tells me the packet gets sent correctly, but unfortunately its source address is 192.168.0.3. As my server is listening on localhost:40001, that means it doesn't receive the packet. I don't want to let the server listen on 0.0.0.0, as it shouldn't receive similar UDP requests that are sent within another network. I can make the server listen within the 192.168.0.0/24 network, but later on it will be listening from another network, that is neither localhost nor 192.168.0.0/24, so that doesn't solve the problem.

Is there a way to choose the source address from which (and the interface via which) the client socket will send its packet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `bind()` yet?  Generally speaking, if you `socket.bind()` to an address (such as `127.0.0.1`) then your packets should originate from that address.  The loopback, and broadcasts for that matter, might be treated specially but `bind()` would be my first choice to try.

Comment: Using bind works, but it's not my preferred solution. It means I have to choose a free port for my client, which you normally leave to the OS. That introduces additional complexity.

Comment: Ah, after reading through some additional C examples, I found I can safely bind to 'dummy' port 0.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're trying to send it out to the loopback device, so it should be something like (never tried this with ruby):

```
dev="lo"
socket.setsockopt(Socket::SOL_SOCKET, Socket::SO_BINDTODEVICE, dev+'\0'))
```

you also might have to enable multicast loop:

```
socket.setsockopt(Socket::SOL_SOCKET, Socket::IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, [1].pack('i'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to set that option. According to e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207746/problems-with-so-bindtodevice-linux-socket-option, SO_BINDTODEVICE requires root privileges. I'd rather not run the application as root.

Comment: uhm.. then listen on 0.0.0.0, and the filter the connections based on ip address.

Comment: That is the fallback plan :).

Answer (score 0):

Answer appearing two years too late, but this might help future StackOverflow users.  It looks like you need to use socket option `IP_MULTICAST_IF`, which takes a network ordered DWORD version of your interface address.  Fortunately the `ipaddr` library has a utility method for converting human readable addresses:

```
address = '127.0.0.1'
hton = IPAddr.new(address).hton
socket.setsockopt(Socket::IPPROTO_IP, Socket::IP_MULTICAST_IF, hton)
```