# how to specify which interface to use for a socket in linux

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

Is it possible to bind a udp socket to a specific interface so it sends data through that interface?  I have an application that uses several Udp Sockets to send data and it is running on a machine with several interfaces.  I know it's possible to do this by specifying the interface name by using this code:

```
int UdpSocket::open(const char *interface)
{
   send_fd_ = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
   if (send_fd_ < 0)
   {
      perror("socket");
      return -1;
   }

   int val = 1;
   int rc = ::setsockopt(send_fd_, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &val, sizeof(val));
   if (rc < 0)
   {
      perror("sesockopt");
      close();
      return -1;
   }

   unsigned char ttl = 16;
   rc = ::setsockopt(send_fd_, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_TTL, &ttl, sizeof(ttl));
   if (rc < 0)
   {
      perror("sesockopt_ttl");
      close();
      return -1;
   }

   if (interface != NULL)
   {
      struct ifreq ifr;

      memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
      snprintf(ifr.ifr_name, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name), interface);
      rc = ::setsockopt(send_fd_, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, (void*)&ifr, sizeof(ifr));

      if (rc < 0)
      {
         perror("sesockopt");
         close();
         return -1;
      }
   }

   const int flags = ::fcntl(send_fd_, F_GETFL, 0);
   ::fcntl(send_fd_, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);

   return 0;
}
```

But this requires that the app is run with root privileges, otherwise it it will throw an error saying the "operation not permitted."

Comment: @E_net4: many reasons, depending on the kind of traffic you want to do. listen only on specific IP. subscribe to multicast traffic on that ip. Chose one of many IPs to appear as the originating IP for connections.

Comment: Can you provide a complete example that we can compile and see for ourselves? It is unclear to me what the other values in ifr and the socket are exactly. I am using that setsockopt fine to bind to interfaces, so it is probably anything of those fields that is wrong. Specifically the port is probably intresting, capabilities wise.

Comment: @E_net4  The app will be communicating with internal components on one network and with clients on a separate network.  When a client connects, the socket may end up getting bound to the wrong interface.

Comment: @PlasmaHH The code is apart of a socket wrapper for a library in my app.  The interface name is passed in, so it would be like "eth0" or "eth2".

Comment: The SO_BINDTODEVICE might be supported by some platforms, but isn't necessarily portable. Did the setsockopt call returned success? If this setsockopt does not work you can use raw sockets, but this requires elevated privileges too.

Comment: @harper Yes it worked, but it required that i run it under the root account.  I would like to be able to do this without having to use the root account.

Comment: The info you require might be in this previous answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207746/problems-with-so-bindtodevice-linux-socket-option

Comment: @gheese There is nothing root-less in the article, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest, and by far the most sane, approach is to add [`route`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/route)(s) matching your multicast destinations:

```
~# route add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 dev eth0
```

since OS network stack selects outbound interface for multicast packets based on the routing table. This also works for listening - you just bind to group address and kernel would pick correct interface for you. You still have to join the group as usual.

Comment: This will not work if incoming multicast traffic is coming over a non-default interface.

Comment: False. Add *non-default* route matching the group for that interface. Then if you have same group mcast traffic on different interfaces - you have bigger problems.

Answer (score 2):

From the manpage:

**SO_BINDTODEVICE**

> Bind this socket to a particular device like “eth0”, as specified in
> the passed interface name.  If the name is an empty string or the
> option length is zero, the
> socket device binding is removed.  The passed option is a variable-length null-terminated interface name string with the
> maximum size of IFNAMSIZ.  If  a  socket
> is  bound  to  an  interface, only packets received from that particular interface are processed by the socket.  Note that this
> only works for some socket types,
> particularly AF_INET sockets.  It is not supported for packet sockets (use normal bind(2) there).

This means you have to get the interface from the name yourself, possibly using [`getifaddrs`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html), and then bind to that address.

Comment: SO_BINDTODEVICE is perfect but only works as root... (you get an 'operation not permitted' otherwise)

Comment: @2072: That is the whole point of the question and the conclusion in this answer is "This means you have to get the interface from the name yourself, possibly using getifaddrs, and then bind to that address. "

Comment: is this available in C#?